# How to get MemberInfo's MemberInfo?

Tags: reflection, enums

the class is here:

```
   public partial class CodeMergeNodeHandler
   {
        [State]
        public enum State
        {
            [Finish]
            [Label("合并成功")]
            Accepted,

            [Start]
            [Label("创建成功")]
            Created,
        }
  }
```

I did had got the MemberInfo of the state:

```
 var members = CodeMergeNodeHandler.GetType().GetMembers();

 MemberInfo memberOfState ;  // the MemberInfo of the Enum State;
 foreach (var member in members)
 {
   var attrs = member.GetCustomAttributes();
   if (attrs.Any(attr => attr is StateAttribute))
   {
        memberOfState = member;
   }
 }
```

I try to get the members of the memberOfState ,the `Accepted` and the `Created`:

```
private static (string start, string end) GetStartEnd(this MemberInfo member)
 {
     var start = default(string);
     var end = default(string);

     var members = member.GetMembers();   //error, here is my question.

    foreach (var sub in members)
    {
      var attrs = sub.GetCustomAttributes();
      if (attrs.Any(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(StartAttribute)))
      {
        start = sub.ToString();
      }
      if (attrs.Any(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(FinishAttribute)))
      {
        end = sub.ToString();
      }
    }

    return (start, end);
}
```

Why `member` have no Method as `GetMembers()`, but  when I Debug like the picture, the target is in the `DeclaredMembers` , and How I can get them ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F27S4.png)

Comment: As I know ,```MemberInfo``` is the base class of ```Type``` .

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question:

```
 Type type  = member as Type;
```

Make the MemberInfo class as the Type class, you can use Methods of Type class.